# HTML table not fetching data from Django only showing heading

Tags: html, css, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm using *HTML, CSS, and Javascript* for the frontend and *Django* for the backend, and *PostgresSQL* for DB. Actually, I have successfully loaded data from the **EXCEL file to Django** and I'm trying to fetch **data from Django to HTML** **Table**. But, I'm getting only headers of the table, not the data. How to fix it.

**index.html**

```
{%extends "base.html"%}
{%block content%}

<html>
<table>
  <thead>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td><strong>{{pro.brand}}</strong></td>
      <td><strong>{{pro.name}}</strong></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
{%endblock%}
```

**views.py**

```
def product(request):
    pro = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'pro': pro})
```

**urls.py (App file)**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('product/', views.product, name='product'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your context variable pro is a queryset(a list of instances), you have to do a loop in template like this:

```
{%extends "base.html"%}
{%block content%}

<html>
<table>
  <thead>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for p in pro %}
    <tr> 
      <td><strong>{{p.brand}}</strong></td>
      <td><strong>{{p.name}}</strong></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody> 
</table>
{%endblock%}
```